# Want to Add Auto Links Variables

Tags: javascript, html

```
var links1 = link2 = link3 = link4 = link5 = ["a.html","b.html","c.html","d.html","e.html","f.html","g.html"]  
function myLinkJS(){
document.write( '<a href=\"'+link1+'\" ></a>\n' );
document.write( '<a href=\"'+link2+'\" ></a>\n' );
document.write( '<a href=\"'+link3+'\" ></a>\n' );
document.write( '<a href=\"'+link4+'\" ></a>\n' );
}
```

The series of Link variables are more than 150 means **var Links1 to Links150** and the same I have to add in href as URL. if there is any solution to add these 150 links easily with any code.

Comment: where do you have them stored? just use a for loop and your document write inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create only one variable (array), filled with objects, and make a loop.

```
var links = [{
  link: "a.html",
  text: "Text A"
}, {
  link: "b.html",
  text: "Text B"
}, {
  link: "c.html",
  text: "Text C"
}];

function myLinkJS() {
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    document.write( '<a href="' + links[i].link + '" >' + links[i].text + '</a>\n' );
  }
}
```

Comment: each **href** has diffrent anchor text

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question (and source code) but I edit my answer : fill the array with objects.